# Don't change slug on update (In Laravel Model)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have a model called `Oglas` with which I create rows in table. It creates a unique slug for that row, but whenever I update that row it generates new slug. So when someone shares a post, then edit, that shared post doesn't exists anymore because slug is changed.

Here is code `Oglas`:

```
    class Oglas extends Model
    {
        protected $table = "oglasi";
        protected $guarded = ['id'];

        public function uniqueSlug($title) {
            $slug = str_slug($title);
            $exists = Oglas::where('slug', $slug)->count();

            if($exists > 0)
                $slug .= "-" . rand(11111, 99999);

            return $slug;
        }

        public function setNazivAttribute($value) // In table i have "naziv" column
        {
            $this->attributes['slug'] = $this->uniqueSlug($value); // I do not want this to fire if post is edited.
            $this->attributes['naziv'] = $value;
        }



}
```

To summarize: When creates new post fire that slug creation, when updating (editing) don't fire, don't change slug.

Comment: what your approach to creating and updating model. I mean your controller's code. Can you show us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like eloquent model `events` is a good way to resolve your problem, If you want to create the slug on post creation only you can use `creating` event.

Define it on your `Oglas.php`:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function ($oglas) {
        $oglas->slug = $this->uniqueSlug($this->naziv);
    });
}
```

Or you can define it on you `AppServiceProvider.php`:

```
public function boot()
{
    ....

    Oglas::creating(function ($oglas) {
        $oglas->slug = $oglas->uniqueSlug($oglass->naziv);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use laravel's create method for this, this way update will not fire. Or use eloquent query to create. This will also protect update of unique row.

Comment: This is in model.  So  I used create and this fires. I used update and this fires

Comment: Use validate method before create in which define rules for unique colomn. And validate your input values.